# Replacing specific values in dataset with Azure ML

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

Lately i've been testing Azure Machine Learning, and i like it. However, when i try to transform my dataset, there's a step that i can't perform easily : replacing a specific value in a column by another one.

The `Missing Values Scrubber` module allows me to deal with undefined values, but in my case i need to change a specific value, or remove rows where that value appears. I don't see which module meets my requirement.

Do you have any suggestion about this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution [there](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bf8f76c7-f976-4552-8553-8e54133ff2c6/replacing-specific-values-in-dataset-with-azure-ml?forum=MachineLearning), by using a `Convert to Dataset` module.